# Ho to call variables items on Joomla Component

Tags: variables, joomla

I'm trying to create my first component in Joomla but I can't understand how it works really :D

I create a basic component with "Component Creator". (I saved a lot of time...).

Now, I have a table in my DB where I've put my data:

```
id = 1
name = Andrea 
note = Ciao
```

Now, I want to call it from the page using Joomla Language.

On my models/component.php i wrote:

```
class Variabili extends JModelLegacy
{
    function estraivariabili()
    {
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 

        $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__table")->loadObjectList();

        return $value;
    }
}
```

and on my `default.php` I wrote

```
$model=$this->Variabili();

//call the method
$items=$model->estraivariabili();

//print
print_r($items);
```

But on the page I have this error:

```
0 Call to undefined method Calcolo_imposteViewCalcoloonline::Variabili()
```

Where is a mistake?

Please be gentle with me because I'm a beginner: D

Thanks in advance

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have committed a few wrongs. I've rewritten your functions so that you can get it. Let's have a look-

The `model`, it looks almost okay. Just change it like-

```
class Variabili extends JModelLegacy
{
    // Make the function public
    public function estraivariabili()
    {
        $db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 

        // Put the result into a variable first, then return it.
        $value = $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__table")->loadObjectList();

        return $value;
    }
}
```

And now call the `model` functions not from `default.php`, rather than write your code inside `view.html.php` file.

Inside the `display` function of `view.html.php` file first, get the `model` instance by using `getModel()` function.

```
$model = $this->getModel();
```

Now you can get the items by using this `$model` class instance.

```
$this->items = $model->estraivariabili();
```

This will bring you the data from the database table. And you can use the data at `default.php` file.

Just try at `default.php` file-

```
print_r($this->items);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply!

I have this error:
Undefined property: Calcolo_imposteViewCalcoloonline::$items

Comment: I don't see any reason for it. Could you please show me the ```display``` function of ```view.html.php``` file.

Comment: Maybe is there the error.
It's too long to put here. I put in a Answer.

Comment: Where is this line ? ```$this->items = $model->estraivariabili();```

Comment: And remove your answer and put those codes into your question.

Comment: Damn it! Nowhere! Where i have to write it? (Thanks again with your patience..!)

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves you problem then mark it as the accepted answer so that others can get help. :)

Comment: no because i don't understand where i have tu put it :D :D Sorry about it...

Comment: Inside the ```display()``` function. Put ```$this->items = $model->estraivariabili();```. Careful there is a ```$this->item``` already there. You can change ```items``` any other variable. It doesn't matter.